# SharePoint 2010 RunWithElevatedPrivileges() Throws Exception

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-foundation, runwithelevatedprivileges

I am trying to update a list item using:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() 
{
    ...

    item.update();**// this line works**
    list.update();**//// exception thrown on this statement**
});
```

When I update the item, it works fine with no exception. But on updating the list... it throws an exception and redirects me to the Access Denied page.

Comment: What is the exception? Also what are you doing to the list that requires an update to it?

Answer (score 2):

you should open new context

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate() 
{
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.current.Site.ID)
    {
       using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb(SPContext.current.Web.ID))
       {
           SPList list = web.Lists["Some List"];
           .....
           item.update();**// this line works**
           list.update();**//// exceptoin throw on this statement**
       }
    }
});
```

Comment: i tried but same issue

Comment: How do you retrieve the list? you should use the web wich is created in the delegate method.

Answer (score 2):

Please ensure you use *SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges* in correct way. Consider below points for the same:

- RunWithElevatedPrivileges  does not work when HTTPContext is null.
- RunWithElevatedPrivileges  does not work for a Sandbox Solution.
- Elevation of privilege occurs only if new SPSite created inside the block.

Below is commonly used WRONG way and you may get access denied:
  
`SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
      SPSite elevatedSite = SPContext.Current.Site;
      using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb())
      {
         // Performing administrative actions here will give Access Denied exception.
      }
   }
});`

**CORRECT Way**:

```
SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
{
   using (SPSite elevatedSite = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.Id))
   {
      using (SPWeb elevatedWeb = elevatedSite.OpenWeb(SPContext.Current.Web.Id))
      {
          // Perform administrative actions by using the elevated site and web objects. 
          // elevatedWeb.CurrentUser.LoginName gives SHAREPOINTsystem          
      }
   }
});
```

Please check out this post for more details:

http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/30/impersonation-elevation-of-privileges/

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
    SPSite mysite = SPContext.Current.Site;
    SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges(delegate()
            {
                SPSite mycurrentsite = new SPSite(mysite.ID);
                SPWeb mycurrentweb = mycurrentsite.OpenWeb();
                mycurrentweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                SPList list = mycurrentweb .Lists["Some List"];      .....
                  item.update();
                  list.update();
                 mycurrentweb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = false;

            });
```